# pUnkOuter parameter of IClassFactory::CreateInstance method

Tags: c++, generics, com

What's the reason behind the `pUnkOuter` parameter of IClassFactory::CreateInstance method?

```
HRESULT CreateInstance(
  [in]   IUnknown *pUnkOuter,
  [in]   REFIID riid,
  [out]  void **ppvObject
);
```

The MSDN's description of `pUnkOuter` parameter notes:

> If the object is being created as part of an aggregate, specify a pointer to the controlling IUnknown interface of the aggregate. Otherwise, this parameter must be NULL.

Can you good people please enlighten me on what is this parameter for?

Answer (score 4):

See [Aggregation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in COM fundamentals. If you create an instance of COM object which is a part of an aggregate, you have to supply so called "outer IUnknown", which is owner COM object interface.